# How to use poll with multicast

Tags: network-programming, multicast

I have used poll in the past where a server has multiple connected file descriptors, but how does one use poll in the case where one wants to listen in to various multicast groups? From my understanding this would entail multiple upd sockets wanting to call recvfrom after joining a group but never connecting these socket..would one just poll on these descriptors anyways and then call recvfrom when the events trigger? Is there any small simple example of this on the web?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The polling is exactly the same - you wait for any of your several sockets to become readable, figure out which one is, and then call `recv(2)` or whatnot. The difference from TCP is that each read on UDP socket de-queues exactly one datagram, so this is a bit easier.

The sockets you put into poll set are usually set to non-blocking, in which case you'd need to handle `EWOULDBLOCK` error from `recv(2)`.

Also remember that UDP is not reliable, so if you are not consuming those datagrams fast enough they fill socket receive buffer and kernel starts dropping them.